# ¿Evitar registros en blanco después de actualizar con Stored Procedure en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Soy nuevo en esto de las bases de datos. Tengo el siguiente Stored Procedure para actualizar mi tabla llamada Paciente:

(Tabla)

```
CREATE TABLE Paciente
(
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    Folio CHAR(6) UNIQUE NULL,
    Nombre NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    S_Nombre NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    Apellido_Paterno NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Apellido_Materno NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Edad SMALLINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Sexo CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    Calle NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    Numero_Domicilio SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED NULL,
    Telefono CHAR(8) NULL,
    Movil CHAR(10) NULL,
    Ocupacion NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    Fecha_Registro DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    Estado BOOLEAN NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
    EstadoCivil_ID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;
```

(SP)

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `actualizarPaciente`
(
IN _param_id INT,
IN _calle NVARCHAR(50),
IN _numdomicilio SMALLINT(4),
IN _telefono CHAR(8),
IN _movil CHAR(10),
IN _ecivil INT 
)
BEGIN
UPDATE Paciente 
SET Calle = (_calle), Numero_Domicilio = (_numdomicilio), Telefono = (_telefono), Movil = (_movil), EstadoCivil_ID = (_ecivil)
WHERE ID = param_id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

El problema es el siguiente:
Cuando el doctor desee actualizar los datos del paciente, no siempre serán los mismos, ni la misma cantidad, pueden ser 2 ó 4, entonces si yo actualizo solo 2 de los 5 parámetros que le estoy pasando y el resto se queda en blanco, en mi tabla "se eliminan" los datos que ya estaban insertados.

Tengo entendido que MySQL toma NULL como un dato válido, pero no sé cómo evitarlo, tenía esta modificación pero sigue sin resultar.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `actualizarPaciente`
(
IN _param_id INT,
IN _calle NVARCHAR(50),
IN _numdomicilio SMALLINT(4),
IN _telefono CHAR(8),
IN _movil CHAR(10),
IN _ecivil INT 
)
BEGIN
UPDATE Paciente 
SET Calle = COALESCE(_calle, Calle), Numero_Domicilio = COALESCE(_numdomicilio, Numero_Domicilio), Telefono = COALESCE(_telefono, Telefono), Movil = COALESCE(_movil, Movil), EstadoCivil_ID = COALESCE(_ecivil, EstadoCivil_ID)
WHERE ID = _param_id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Cómo llamas al SP cuando hay menos parámetros? Pasas explícitamente NULL?

Comment: Tu stored procedure con `COALESCE` debería funcionar correctamente, siempre y cuando realmente estás pasando `NULL` cuando deseas "ignorar" un parámetro. Ojo que una cadena vacía no es lo mismo que `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Te doy un ejemplo

declare vari INT DEFAULT 0;

update `tu_tabla_new` f

SET f.`SinMod` = CASE WHEN vari = 0 THEN f.`SinMod` ELSE vari END;

Como verás, el campo se modifica si la variable trae algún valor, sino lo deja como estaba.

Saludos desde Uruguay

Chiquito